# How to use SELECT multiple (500 000) times in one script?

Tags: php, mysql, import

I'm trying to solve problem with update or insert new product into database from file (csv).

Problem is that in CSV file are only Number and Supplier of product. So i need for every product look for ID with this supplier and number. If product is not located i need to insert new one otherwise i will just update storage info and price.

That csv have 500 000 products (34MB).

Now I'am solving this with code like this (but script stops after 50 000 file rows because of no memory space (used 2GB):

```
        while (!feof($file_handle)) 
    {   
        $data = fgetcsv($file_handle,5096,$i->column_separator);

        if($row >= ($i->firstrow-1) && !empty($data[$i->column_product_code-1]) && !empty($data[$i->column_product_name-1]) && !empty($data[$i->column_price-1]) && $data[$i->column_price-1] > 0)
        {                            
            @$code = str_replace(array(' ','.','-','/'),'',$data[$i->column_product_code-1]);
            @$supplier = iconv('WINDOWS-1250','UTF-8', $data[$i->column_producer_name-1]);
            @$name = iconv('WINDOWS-1250','UTF-8', $data[$i->column_product_name-1]);

            $article = $articleModel->searchImport($code,$supplier,isset($data[$i->column_producer_code-1]) ? $data[$i->column_producer_code-1]:NULL);

            if($article !== FALSE)
            {
                $importqueueModel->update()
            }
            else
            { 
                $importqueueModel->insert()
            }
```

I cant figure out any different steps how to match product code and supplier from file to get ID from database so I can update or insert new product back into database.

Please help, any tips would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You get some error ? Could you please provide exactly what's written ?

Comment: Do you really need to do this? Have you looked at mysqlimport? 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule of thumb, if you think you need to run hundreds of queries in a script then you're doing it wrong. Thousands? Very wrong.

Don't load the data from the CSV directly into a target table which already contains live data - load it into a staging table - then a single insert....select will populate the related records:

```
INSERT INTO suppliers (name, status)
SELECT c.supplier, 'new'
FROM csv_imported c
LEFT JOIN suppliers s
ON c.supplier=s.name
WHERE s.name is NULL
AND c.supplier IS NOT NULL;
```

And using the mysqlimport / load data infile eliminates the need for a lot of the code too.

> because of no memory space (used 2GB)

Even doing it the wrong way doesn't cause this problem - you've got bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you are storing data about each line read from the CSV file. This does not appear to be contained in the incomplete snippet you've posted, unless it is part of the `$articleModel->searchImport()` method call.

If you're lucky, the error/exception message that you've helpfully omitted from your post might point directly to the line in question.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new method in your `$importQueueModel` to support the MySQL extended INSERT syntax `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`. 
This wouldn't be portable, but would solve your current problem.

Another (better) solution is to write a MySQL script to handle the update. You could modify your PHP script to output the SQL, and then run it separately.

The [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert.html) reference manual.